# from a list of lat/lon coordinates, how does one return a list of streets nearby in the format of (streetname,State Abbreviation) ex. Oaktree ln, TX?

Tags: geolocation, gis, openstreetmap

from a list of lat/lon coordinates, how does one return a list of streets nearby in the format of (streetname,State Abbreviation) ex. Oaktree ln, TX from open street map?

Comment: Maybe you can try to ask it at http://gis.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

You should determine for yourself what exactly is 'nearby' and how many streets you want in your list. You could then look into some services based on OSM to get what you want exactly. [Nominatim](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim#Reverse_Geocoding_.2F_Address_lookup) performs reverse geocoding and might be what you want.